# JS Charts and PHP

Tags: charts

I am using JS Charts to draw 'bar' chart and I don't know how to build the XML file data with data collected from the DataBase?

This is how I prepare XML data but It doesn't work, could you please help me?

```
<SCRIPT>var strXML = <JSChart><dataset type='bar'><data unit='Delivered' value='29/><data unit='Pending' value='9/><data unit='Rejected' value='6/><data unit='Unknown' value='/></dataset><colorset>
<color value='#7979DB'/>
<color value='#7952E9'/>
<color value='#792BC8'/>
<color value='#792BA1'/>
</colorset><optionset>
<option set='setAxisValuesColo' value= '#008'/>
<option set='setAxisColor' value='#ABABAB'/>
<option set='setAxisWidth' value='1'/>
<option set='setAxisValuesColor' value='#858585'/>
<option set='setAxisNameColor' value='#858585'/>
<option set='setBarBorderColor' value='#bbb'/>
<option set='setBarOpacity' value='0.8'/>
<option set='setBarSpacingRatio' value='50'/>
<option set='setBarValues' value='false'/>
<option set='setTitleColor' value='#928888'/>
<option set='setGridColor' value='#ABABAB'/>
</optionset></JSChart>;</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/image/mobiletool/calander/js/jscharts.js"></script>
<div id="graph">Loading graph...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
myChart.setDataXML(strXML);
myChart.draw();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are creating the XML in PHP but not passing it over to JS. You effectively need to echo out your $strXML for JS to be able to use it. Something along the lines of this:

```
echo "<SCRIPT>";
echo "var strXML = \"". $strXML ."\";";
echo "</SCRIPT>";
```

If you echo out this before your JS then you just need to change:

```
myChart.setDataXML('$strXML');
```

to

```
myChart.setDataXML(strXML);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Raul, the error gone but it did not display anything. even there is a data, would you please see if there is any problem with the format of   <option set='setAxisValuesColo' value= '#008'/>

Comment: in the example it is like this : <option set="setAxisValuesColor" value="'#008'"/>

Comment: There isnt anything necessarily wrong with that. Can you post the whole completed xml or at least a section of it? If you are using Chrome, you can also hit "Control+Shit+I" and click on console to see if there are any javascript errors that might be breaking this.

Comment: This is the error from consoe: Uncaught ReferenceError: $strXML is not defined. Which XML file do you mean? for the example this one:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <JSChart><dataset type="bar">
  
  <data unit="2008" value="5.2"/>
 </dataset>
 <colorset>
  
  <color value="#792B79"/>
 </colorset>
 <optionset>
  
  <option set="setBarBorderColor" value="'#bbb'"/>
  <option set="setBarOpacity" value="0.8"/>
  <option set="setBarSpacingRatio" value="50"/>
  <option set="setBarValues" value="false"/>
  <option set="setTitleColor" value="'#928888'"/>
  <option set="setGridColor" value="'#ABABAB'"/>
 </optionset>
</JSChart>

Comment: in Firefox consloe :syntax error var strXML = ;

$strXML is not defined

Comment: ok, so, the console error is saying that you are still using "$strXML" in your JS when you should be using the variable you echoed out, if you called it "strXML" it should be that not "$strXML". Find the line where you are using that variable.

Comment: Ok, so you are not echoing out the $strXML properly. Check the syntax I posted above and make sure you have copied it as is or post the changes you made.

Comment: Dear, please see my original post, i have update with what I found in firefox console. I coudn't find the error where?

Comment: I just made a tweak to my code, it was missing the quotes surrounding the xml.

Comment: Thanks. but it gives now :unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error] var strXML = "<JSChart><dataset type='...wn' value=''/></dataset><colorset>

Comment: and also: strXML is not defined
 myChart.setDataXML(strXML);

Comment: Reading the documentation, it doesn't look like you can pass an XML string to the function. It expects it to be an actual file. I'll have another play but I am not sure this is the right way to do it.

Comment: In fusion charts I did the same way, but in this I guess there should be a way to do it, or how it can be used with php ?

Comment: I would advise you read the documentation here: http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use

Comment: I lost in the documentation, ^_^

Comment: As I understood that data should be in XML or JSON format, but how JSCharts could be integrated with PHP & Mysql ?

Comment: Your approach is in the right direction but, if you look at the functions the setDataXML function requires an actual file. You need to understand that Stackoverflow is a Q&A site not a tutorial website. You need to have a play at writing this yourself and, when you get stuck, post it as a question. In simple terms, for this to work, my suggestion is that you need to either: store the xml or json file on the server and call it with the method you have used or use the array functionality for which you will need to echo out the variable from php in a similar manner as you already have. Good Luck.